# Difference between 守る and 護る

Tags: kanji, kanji-choice

Both 守 and 護 mean "to protect" or "to safeguard", but are there any differences between them?

Comment: Do you mean the difference between まもる when written as 守る and as 護る? That's the the actual verb written with the kanji. If you have questions about the kanji themselves, it might help to explain what you want to know a bit more clearly.

Comment: It was actually about the verbs, but I fixed it

Comment: @naruto Oh, I don`t know with it didn`t pop out when I was writing the question. I'll delete this question then

Comment: No need to delete. Duplicates aren't a bad thing (assuming you made a genuine effort to research in the first place). They can actually help people by giving them multiple ways to look up the same information.